# How do I correctly format my nav bar so that all the categories are side by side?

Tags: html, css

[image: What its supposed to look like]

[image: What it currently looks like]

I've looked over the CSS a bunch but can't figure it out. My css skills seem to be a lot worse than I thought. Here's the link to the code pen. [codepen](https://codepen.io/crismanrique/pen/WNozgKb)

Basically the about tab is not where it's supposed to be, as you can see in the picture. This is the only part I'm having trouble with. I've looked in the nav css section, but haven't been able to deduce why this is happening. Any help is appreciated

```
#nav_menu {
    position: relative;
}

#nav_menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav_menu ul li {
    float: left;
}

#nav_menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 1em 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #800000;
}

#nav_menu a.current {
    color: yellow;
}

#nav_menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav_menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav_menu >ul::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
#nav_menu ul ul li{
    float: none;
}
```

Posting this code because stackoverflow is making me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header is dipping into the nav bar. Try this:

```
header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or this:

```
header::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yup that first block of code did it. How did you notice that if I may ask?

Comment: You can see the logo image is about the same width as the unwanted space, and you're using floats and clears, so tested in the codepen and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table tag to easily align the buttons in menu bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
*{
    margin:0;
}
#head{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:15px;
    position:fixed;
}
#btns{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:63px;
    width:100%;
    background:#0f6600;
}
input[type=button]{
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    background:#0f6600;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=button]:hover{
    color:yellow;
}
</style>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nav Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="head">
        Navigation Bar In HTML
    </div>
<table cellspacing="0" id="btns"><tr><td>
<input type="button" value="Home"><td>
<input type="button" value="Speakers"><td>
<input type="button" value="Luncheons"><td>
<input type="button" value="Tickets"><td>
<input type="button" value="About us"><td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```